# Changing Global Variables in Python

Tags: python, global-variables

I want to modify a global variable from a function in Python 2.7

```
x = 0
def func():
    global x
    x = 2
```

If I load this code in the interpreter, and then run func(), x remains 0. How do I modify the value of x from within a function?

EDIT: Here's a screenshot of the interpreter and source code. I'm not sure why it works for others and not for me.
http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/9567/screenshotfrom201304222.png

Comment: This works as-is for me. Are you sure you've called the function? I paste your code in, call `func()`, and `print x`. I get 2.

Comment: What are you talking about? It still works.

Comment: You could try printing all `globals()` in `func()` to see if `x` is included.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very interesting situation. When I ran your code from an interpreter with `from mytest import *` I encountered the same issue:

```
>>> from mytest import *
>>> x
0
>>> func()
>>> x
0
```

However, when I just did `import mytest` and ran it from there:

```
>>> import mytest
>>> mytest.x
0
>>> mytest.func()
>>> mytest.x
2
```

It turned out fine! The reason, I believe, comes from a line in http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement:

> Names listed in a global statement must not be defined as formal
>   parameters or in a for loop control target, class definition, function
>   definition, or import statement.

Looks like because it is a parameter in your import statement (by importing all), `global` is having trouble with it. Do you need to `import *`, or can you simply import the module whole?